# Use of .ToLower yields greek charcacters

Tags: .net

I am trying to simply convert a string to lowercase.

```
Input: "Ρ Αir"
Output: "ρ αir"



  Dim strInput as string = "P Air"
  Dim strLower as string = strInput.ToLower
```

`strLower` results in the above output. I've tried setting the culture of the thread to en-US with no success and also tried using encoding.getencoding with as many different options as I could think of. Also `StrConv` produces the same result.

Comment: Are you sure the character in question is the 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P' (U+0050) and not the 'GREEK CAPITAL LETTER RHO' (U+03A1) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your input is greek. It's only looks like english.